# Can I really check an instance variable in a block like this?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

[This tutorial](http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/27/a-simple-job-queue-with-grand-central-dispatch/) suggests that you can do this:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    if (_valid) {
        [self processFile:fileURL];
    }
});
```

But I am skeptical. Blocks copy the value of the variables (capturing scope). So _valid would be YES or NO depending on what it was when I created this block. The block would use this captured value and not look up the actual value of the instance variable. Correct?

Comment: See [Blocks and Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW3) section of _Blocks Programming Topics_, which observes that blocks maintain strong references to the referenced objects (or for ivars, to implicitly to `self`), not copying them.

Answer (score 5):

> The block would use this captured value and not look up the actual value of the instance variable. Correct?

No. In the case of instance variables, `self` is captured and the instance variable is evaluated as `self->_valid`, i.e. the value at the time the block is run.

This is why you get a warning from ARC in some cases like this, about implicitly capturing `self` can cause a reference cycle.

This is also another reason you should always use the properties, not the instance variables directly. It makes it clear and explicit that `self` is captured, not the property.

Comment: "It makes it clear and explicit that self is captured, not the property." Well, if you wrote `self->_valid` it would also be clear and explicit that `self` is captured.